# Powershell: Send keys to 3rd party application in the background

Tags: powershell, automation, background, sendkeys

I am trying to automate a process: I have developed a powershell script that sends keys to a 3rd party application, it works fine when I am logged in. However I need it to run when I am not logged into my machine, which it is failing to do. I would appreciate suggestions for how I can tackle this problem or provide resources which I can peruse to accomplish this task. Thank you!

```bsh
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#-- Start Application
start-process -filepath "<filepath for third party app here>"
timeout 30 

#-- Focus on main window: 
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("<third party app>") 

#-- Send Keys
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}")
timeout 3
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(" ")
timeout 5
```

Comment: What is your script?

Comment: Hi Neko, please refer the image I have now included in my post (first few lines of code). It basically calls the application, gives it time to load, ensures that the application window is active, then sends a series of key strokes until the task is accomplished.

Comment: postanote I have removed the image and input an excerpt of the code. What would be a suitable way to go about tackling my problem? There is no CLI for this application.

Comment: Based on your use case, it cannot be done due to who interactive GUI apps implemented/operationalized. Apps are installed to a user hive, be it a single user or all users. A user must be logged on to use them because of the profile required to use them. GUI requires focus (hence your AppActivate with SendKeys or other GUI automation tool), thus in a logged off/screen locked state the Window lock screen (the is the point where the WinLogon/GINA is waiting for input) has control until you unlock/logon, thus no other GUI will ever get focus, thus no interaction possible.

Comment: Lastly, PowerShell always runs in the context of the user who started it. So, that is really 2 interactive sessions, both needing a logged on profile to work. If your app does not have a CLI, then there is little any automation language that can do anything your defiend use case.